# Manipulando listas em Elixir

Tags: elixir

Estou iniciando na linguagem Elixir e gostaria de saber se há um repositório de 'modules' criado e alimentado pela comunidade e que são amplamente utilizados em projetos, gerando produtividade e confiabilidade pela sua maturidade na implementação.

Em minhas pesquisas, acabei achando exemplos de módulos isolados e com um fim especifico, disponibilizado pela comunidade.

Ex:

- Manipulação de Listas
- Manipulação de Json
- Manipulação de Strings, com operações de Split, Trim, etc..
- Outros tipos de manipulações

Caso não exista, no dia-a-dia vocês mesmos acabam implementando as operações que são necessarias?

Comment: Jason ou Poison para manipular JSON. O próprio módulo nativo String para strings. E o nativo Enum ou List para listas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A biblioteca padrão do Elixir é bem completa nesse sentido e possui alguns módulos para as operações que você citou:

- Manipulação de listas: [`Enum (nativo)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html), [`List (nativo)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html)
- Manipulação de JSON: [`Enum (nativo)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html), [`Map (nativo)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html), [`Poison`](https://github.com/devinus/poison), [`Jason`](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason)
- Manipulação de strings: [`String (nativo)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html)

Veja que o módulo `Enum` aparece em diversos casos, pois é uma coleção de funções de tudo que responda ao protocolo [`Enumerable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enumerable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que vc esteja falando sobre um gerenciador de pacotes do Elixir como NPM do Javascript. O gerenciador utilizado é o Hex (https://hex.pm/).